# What is the indefinite integral of $x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I get this but I don't know if it is correct. I used a reduction formula for $\tan^{2n}(x)\sec^{3}(x)$. Any help would be appreciated.
My Final Answer:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1} x}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1} x^3}{4}-\frac{\log|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x|}{2}+C$$

Comment: so what do you get?

Comment: @sanjab sorry picture was incorrectly uploaded. It is fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution should be:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1} x}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1} x^3}{4}-\frac{\sinh^{-1}(x)}{8}+C$$

Considering that $\sinh^{-1}(x) = \log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$
your solution looks almost correct.

Comment: oh whoops forgot to carry a 1/4 to make the last term have a denominator of 8. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $x=\sinh t$, and use the fact that $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1,~\sinh't=\cosh t,~\sinh2t=$ $=2\sinh t\cosh t$, and substitute $u=e^t$. Alternately, let $x=\tan y$, and use the fact that $\tan'y=$ $=1+\tan^2y=\sec^2y$, along with the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).

Comment: Thanks! I did it the way substituting x = tany, just wanted to make sure my algebra wasnt screwed up along the way.